# How to setup a linear relation between three column matrices?

Tags: matrices, systems-of-equations, matrix-equations

[image]

I tried setting up the systems of equations like $4a+8b+4c = 0$, etc. and solving for the variables. I used rref on my calculator and it gave me a solution where $c = 0$ and $a$ and $b$ were both non-zero numbers. However this solution was wrong. Can someone tell me where to start with this question?

Comment: If you include in your question the matrix that you fed into your calculator, that will greatly increase the chances that someone will point out where you went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

Solve the system

$$\begin{bmatrix}
4 & 8 & 4\\
-5 & -10 & -5\\
-3 & -1 & -2\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
a \\
b \\
c \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
0 \\
0 \\
0 \end{bmatrix}$$

if the only solution is $a=b=c=0$ then the given vectors are linearly independent.

Your solution with $c=0$ seems to be not correct since the first two vectors are linearly independent.